# SQL Server Session for an Asp.Net MVC application

Tags: asp.net-mvc, sql-session-state

Isn't SQL Server sessioning for an ASP.NET MVC application fundamentally the same as ASP.NET?  If so, do you guys traditionally impersonate your front end user for the sessioning database or setup a static SQL Server user?  Just trying to setup our permissions for our MVC app.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Really depends where you host your app. If it's inside your intranet then impersonation might be best. If it's a public site then you're best setting up a static login.